# Tradingview Pine Script alert based on candle color from

Tags: alert, pine-script, candlestick-chart

[image][image]I have a paid subscription for an indicator however the code for the indicator is not provided. The indicator changes the colors of the candles when necessary.

I am trying to setup an alert when the candle changes to a specific color, for example if the candle with color #983598 appears an alert will occur.

I have strated the following however this is the first time I have used PineScript and am a noob

```
study("PURPLE PIVOTS")

alertcondition(????????????, title='PURPLE PIVOTS', message='pivot is PURPLE !')
```

Comment: Read this [article](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000474048/)

Comment: Thank you for providing, however the "Add Indicator/Strategy on…" option does not appear for this indicator probably because there is some lock on the paid indicator.  Still think the only way is a PineScript that detects a purple colored candle

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer. I can't fix all the errors remotely.

Comment: No problem mate thanks for your help.  I'll do a bounty for this question.  But I think it lies in creating a script based on the color of the candle as the "Add Indicator/Strategy on…" isn't accessible

Comment: I added an image above.  Lets say I would like a script for an alert when you see an Orange colored candle #FF7F00

Comment: I believe it requires this manual way of actually looking for the candle on a colored basis as when I export the chart data from tradingview it gives no data around the type of candle or color

Comment: I did some additional research, but I can't get the color from the external indicator. If only someone from the pine development team can suggest a workaround.

Comment: Does the paid indicator expose any alerts? By this I mean, can you add alerts on that indicator? Do you have a link to that indicator's TradingView page?

Comment: Hi Bjorn.  I added a 2nd picture to show the alert options. The indicator actually does not look available for purchase anymore however I purchased it years ago and it remained on my account

Comment: I don't think this can be done, unless the color change coincides with one of the exposed alerts, in which case you could use that alert.